# How can i detach from integrated tomcat from a springboot application

Tags: java, docker, containers, detach

I have a project in springboot, and when i run `mvn spring-boot:run` it deploy the app with a embeded tomcat, i need to run a container with tomcat, and compile the app to a WAR, and add it to the tomcat container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks man by answering me, finally i figured out how to do it.

First to access admin dashboard of Tomcat, we need to create a set of files like this:

```
-MySpringBootApp
|-->src
|----|->myspringbootapppackage
|------------------|->MySpringBootApp.java
|-->Dockerfile
|-->tomcat-users.xml
|-->pom.xml
```

at `tomcat-users.xml` i wrote like this

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="asd123" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

At my `Dockerfile` i wrote like this:

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre8-alpine
LABEL maintainer="myemail@myemail.mytld"
EXPOSE 8080
ARG WAR_FILE=target/myappbuilded-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
ARG TOMCAT_USERS_FILE=tomcat-users.xml
ADD ${WAR_FILE} /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myappbuilded.war
ADD ${TOMCAT_USERS_FILE} /usr/local/tomcat/conf
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

At my `pom.xml` i added this plugin at dependecies and also add at the top of the file the node with name `packaging`

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
</dependencies>
    ...other dependencies ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Finally at `MySpringBootApp.java` i just add an extends from `SpringBootServletInitializer` and also add an override method `configure` the file looks like this:

```
package myspringbootpackage;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MySpringBootApp.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thats it! finally i just compile my app by running `mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true` disabling the tests, and once the app is compiled to `target` directory, and i compiled the docker image with `sudo docker build -t myspringbootappcontainer .` inside the app directory ofcourse. Finally run my container by running `sudo docker run -p 5000:8080 myspringbootappcontainer`. Thats it :) Hope it helps the most to other developers :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to exclude the tomkat from the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

After this add the WAR package worflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spring's documentation on how to [convert a spring boot JAR application to a WAR](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/).